# Display message in repeater when no row found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET repeater and I want to display **No Row Found** message when query return 0 rows from database. I know its there in GridView.

Regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a `HeaderTemplate` or a `FooterTemplate` defined, you could add any `HtmlControl` or `ServerControl` inside of either of them and then programatically show/hide it in the codebehind.

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="">
 <HeaderTemplate>
  <h1>My Repeater Data</h1>
  <div id="NoRecords" runat="server" visible="false">
    No records are available.
  </div>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 ...
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here's the code behind

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (Repeater1.Items.Count < 1)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl noRecordsDiv = (e.Item.FindControl("NoRecords") as HtmlGenericControl);
            if (noRecordsDiv != null) {
              noRecordsDiv.Visible = true;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize this is an old accepted answer, but if you use this code it will not work. In the markup side you are using HeaderTemplate, and in the code-behind you are attempting to load the No Records div for ListItemType.Footer. In order to work the code-behind should be updated to ListItemType.Header.

Comment: also you can use hidden div outside the repeater element and check array for visible that ;)

Answer (score 4):

Think about using the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb459902.aspx) control instead that has an [EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.emptydatatemplate.aspx) for use when the data source has no data. If you opt to stick with the `Repeater` control, think about testing your query for records and optionally displaying a `Label` or `Literal` that has your "no row found" message instead of your repeater.

```
if (query.Any())
{
    repeater.DataSource = query;
    repeater.DataBind();
}
else
{
    noRecordsLiteral.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example to demonstrate Displaying **No Record Found** in a **Repeater** control.

```
<div id="NoRecords" runat="server" visible="false">
        No records are available.
</div>
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server" OnPreRender="Repeater1_PreRender">
 <HeaderTemplate>
  <h1>My Repeater Data</h1>

 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 ...
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the Code-Behind

```
protected void Repeater1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Repeater1.Items.Count < 1)
    {
        NoRecords.Visible = true;
        Repeater1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion. Neat.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by altering the logic in the repeater or by providing data to the repeater that drives the behavior you want.  I prefer that the repeater is left out of it.  It's a keep your logic out of the view thing if you are familiar with MVC.

I am saving space here by using a List as the data source instead of a database result but the principle is the same.  You would probably have a collection of IDataRecord as your source if you are returning from a DB.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflowRepeater
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            repeater.ItemDataBound += HandleRepeaterItemDataBound;

            var data = new List<string>();

            if (!data.Any())    // could also be data.Count < 1
            {
                data.Add("No Row Found");
            }

            repeater.DataSource = data;
            repeater.DataBind();

            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        void HandleRepeaterItemDataBound (object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item))
            {
                var span = (HtmlGenericControl) e.Item.FindControl("output");
                span.InnerText = e.Item.DataItem.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming the following mark-up:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="StackOverflowRepeater.Default" %>
<html>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater id='repeater' runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span id='output' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I done something following;

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
      <% if (Repeater.Items.Count < 1)
      { %>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="3">No data found.</td>
        </tr>
      <% }
      else { %>
         <tr>
             <th>Case Id</th>
             <th>Claim Id</th>
             <th>Notes</th>
         </tr>
      <% } %>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="2"><%# Eval("CaseId") %></td>
         <td rowspan="2">
            <a href="ClaimsManagement.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ClaimId") %>"><%# Eval("ClaimId") %></a>
         </td>
         <td><%# Eval("Note") %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%# Eval("CreatedBy") %> : <%# Eval("CreatedDate") %></td>                              
      </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

CSS

```
.div-no-display {
    display: none;
}
```

Code Behind - Usually don't bind it if its empty in that case you have to put the div outside the repeater, but if you bind 0 items you can put it in the header template

```
 this.Repeater.DataSource = ChildLinksList;
                            this.Repeater.DataBind();
 public List<Link> ChildLinksList { get; set; }
```

Page

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <div id="NoRecords" class='<%= ChildLinksList.Count > 0 ? "div-no-display" : "" %>'>
         No child links active.
    </div>
</HeaderTemplate>
```